# how to get values in jsp page to return from spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am getting values from DAO its stored in varaible `editVal` and page return to edit.jsp now how to get varaible `editVal` values in edit.jsp page..

Controller page:

```
@RequestMapping(value="edit", method=RequestMethod.GET)//String 
public ModelAndView  callgetSuccess(@ModelAttribute("id")String Id, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {     
    ModelAndView shop=new ModelAndView();
     shopModel shModel=new shopModel();     
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        System.out.println("error");
        return new ModelAndView("edit","shopModel",editVal);//"edit"
    }else{                  
        shModel = shopService1.editshop(Id);            
        model.addAttribute("shopModel",shModel);
        shop.addObject("shopModel", shModel);
        return new ModelAndView("edit","shopModel",shModel);
    }
```

edit.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<form>
<h1>Success</h1>
edit page

<c:out value="${id}" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit.jsp Page Imge
[edit jsp page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F8vK.png)

Comment: ${shopModel}. Just as any other request attribute.

Comment: You can keep in session attribute in controller and access tht in jsp

Answer (score 0):

As `editVal` is a string, you can access it `<c:out value="${shopModel}" />`
If its a list of string, then the following can be used

```
<c:forEach var="shop" items="${shopModel}">
        <c:out value="${shop}" />
</c:forEach>
```

If its a list of objects, then `var.<object attribute name>` as follows

```
    <c:forEach items="${shopModel}" var="shop"> 
      <tr>
        <td>${shop.name}</td>
        <td>${shop.number}</td>
        ...
      </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: my return values is object but im unable to get values in jsp page

Comment: what does that object contain? Can you add some code?

Comment: pls see above image

Comment: I am  modified controller page pls check above ...   shModel   return values in object...

Comment: have you included `<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>` in your page? It is appearing as ${shop.storeName}. Once included, you can use `<c:out value="${shopModel.storeName}" />`
`